# UINavigationController does not take the precedent view title

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, tableview

- I've a simple view titled *"firstView"* (using this code in the ViewDidLoad method : `[self setTitle:@"firstView"`), which contains just one
  button. When I click on this button, my app show an other view
  (called *"secondView"*), thanks to the following code :

  ```
  - (IBAction)btnShowAnOtherView:(id)sender
  {
      secondView *secondView = [[secondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondView" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
  }
  ```

  Then, the new view (i.e *"secondView"*) set automatically the
  navigation bar back button title to *"firstView"*. **So all works
  fine**.
- I've a simple view titled *"thirdView"* (using this code in the ViewDidLoad method : `[self setTitle:@"thirdView"`), wich contains a UITableView.
  When I click on a cell, my app show an other view (called
  *"fourthView"*), thanks to the following code :

  ```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     fourthView *fourthView = [[fourthView alloc] initWithNibName:@"fourthView" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:fourthView animated:YES];
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  }
  ```

  But the new view (i.e *"fourthView"*) has a navigation bar back button title set to *"Back"*, not to *"thirdView"*. **Why ?**

Here is the thirdView : http://imageshack.us/a/img818/8886/ldp9.png

Here is the fourthView : http://imageshack.us/a/img33/2444/5y0k.png

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Where do you set the title of the third view?

Comment: I set it in the ViewDidLoad method of my thirdView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will happen when you are not setting thirdview title.
but you are setting the title as described in your answer.
check if your title of third view is displaying on you navigationbar or not?

Comment: Yes, the title of thirdView is displaying on the navigation bar.

Comment: Please see my post, I modified it by adding the screenshots.

Comment: i think the name of the view controller is too long. try to make it short. try it with eg. "Lites des petiants" replace with "abc" only

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's strange because before the update to ios 7, it was displaying the full title, or a part of the title if it was too long. Thanks for your help !